# python/selenium problem : ERR_CONNECTION_RESET (when using proxy)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, connection-reset

when i use proxy this error appear
when disable proxy server option , it work fine
what the problem and can anyone help
this is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import random
import profiles
import threading
def adnan():
    i=0
    proxy= profiles.proxies[i]
    ua=profiles.useragent[i]
    options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua}')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s'%proxy)
    #options.add_extension('chameleon.xpi')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.headless = False
    s=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
    s.implicitly_wait(5)
    s.get("https://proxs.ru/myreferer.php")
    i= 1+i
    time.sleep(100)
for e in range(5):
     threading.Thread(target=adnan).start()
     time.sleep(3)
```

note: the import profile is .py folder contain the proxy as array ,
which read other file called validproxy.text and readlines in array variable called proxies
it is properly read lines and it work fine when calling profile.proxies
i test the proxy everytime before i using the proxy and it working

this is the error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x01016643]
    (No symbol) [0x00FABE21]
    (No symbol) [0x00EADA9D]
    (No symbol) [0x00EA9E22]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9FCFD]
    (No symbol) [0x00EA1101]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9FFDD]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9F3BC]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9F2D8]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9DC68]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9E512]
    (No symbol) [0x00EAF75B]
    (No symbol) [0x00F17727]
    (No symbol) [0x00EFFD7C]
    (No symbol) [0x00F16B09]
    (No symbol) [0x00EFFB76]
    (No symbol) [0x00ED49C1]
    (No symbol) [0x00ED5E5D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0128A142+2497106]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012B85D3+2686691]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012BBB9C+2700460]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010C3B10+635936]
    (No symbol) [0x00FB4A1F]
    (No symbol) [0x00FBA418]
    (No symbol) [0x00FBA505]
    (No symbol) [0x00FC508B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76B6FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775A7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775A7A6E+238]
```

i think the error is in the chrome itself or such in windows 10 , also tried firefox , same thing
"this site cant be reached"
delete the cache and try the common solution on internet and the same problem
i didnt try windows 7 , so
what can do ?